# How can I loop through an index and keep the associated row information?

Tags: python, arrays, list, for-loop, indexing

I have a loop within my function that is supposed to find the max rate, min rate, and compute the average, and the function that I wrote is doing this right, but how can I keep the row information when I find the max, and min within my data? I'm a beginner at python, but here is the loop that I have.

```
    max_rate = -1 
    min_rate = 25 
    count = 0 
    sum = 0
    with open(file_names, "r") as file_out:
   # skips the headers in the file
      next(file_out)
      for line in file_out: 
         values = line.split(",")
 # since rate is index 6 that is what we are going to compare to values above
        if float(values[6]) > max_rate: 
           max_rate = float(values[6])
        if float(values[6]) < min_rate:
           min_rate = float(values[6])
     count += 1
  # sum up all rates in the rates column
     sum = float(values[6]) + sum 
     avg_rate = sum / count
     print(avg_rate)
```

I have printed the average just to test my function. Hopefully the question I am asking makes sense, I don't just want the 6th index but I want the rest of the row information that has the min or the max. An example would be to get the company name, state, zip, and rate.  Don't worry about indentations, I don't know if I formatted it right in the code block here, but all the indents are right in my code chunk.

Comment: Use `max` and `min` with a `key` function.  `max(lines, key=lambda x: x[6])`

Comment: `for i, line in enumerate(file_out):` gives you both, the line number and the line content. You can then update a `line_max` and `line_min` counter together with your rates. BTW, what should be the output, if the max/min values is more than once in your data set?

Comment: Thanks so much, I also had a follow up question to your response, say I didn't want all the row information, but still wanted a few pieces within that row, would this still work, or should I go about it a different way.

Comment: and to answer your question the output should take the first max it comes across or first min if the max or min are repeated.

Comment: The advantage of the enumerate method is, that you have at the end of your loop your count as `i + 1`. But you can of course also run a separate variable like `count`. Your code.

Comment: oh nice, I didn't know that method did that, like I said earlier, I'm just learning Python, so still have a lot to learn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're working with CSV or other table-like data. [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) handles this really well. An example would be:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('something.csv')
print(df)

print(f'\nMax Rate: {df.rate.max()}')
print(f'Avg Rate: {df.rate.mean()}')
print(f'Min Rate: {df.rate.min()}')
print(f'Last Company (Alphabetically): {df.company_name.max()}')
```

Yields:

```
    company_name         state    zip    rate
0  Company1 Inc.         Texas  76189  0.6527
1  Company2 LLC.  Pennsylvania  18657  0.7265
2  Company3 Corp       Indiana  47935  0.5267

Max Rate: 0.7265
Avg Rate: 0.6353
Min Rate: 0.5267
Last Company (Alphabetically): Company3 Corp
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
max_rate = []
min_rate = [] 
count = 0
total = 0

with open(file_names, "r") as file_out:
  # skips the headers in the file
  next(file_out)

  # reset max, min, total sum and count
  max_rate = []
  min_rate = []
  total = 0
  count = 0
  for line in file_out: 
    values = line.split(",")
    max_rate = max(values, max_rate or values, key=lambda x: x[6])
    min_rate = min(values, min_rate or values, key=lambda x: x[6])

    # sum up all rates in the rates column
    total += float(values[6])
    count += 1

  avg_rate = total / count
  print(avg_rate)
```

This will attribute the whole list for the `min` and `max` related to the 6th column as you intended. The `max_rate or values` code will evaluate the maximum value between `values` and `max_rate` lists only if max_rate is not empty (that will be the case in the first interaction of the for loop) that will prevent an `IndexError`. Same thing for `min_rate`

An important change I've made on your code is the name for the variable `sum`. That's a Python registered keyword and it's not a good practice to use it as a variable name, so prefer using something like `total` or `total_sum` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Those suggestions are great. Thanks, I also found out that I could just assign the line to a variable underneath my if statements as well. And then at the beginning of my function I can assign this variables to an empty string. Like

```
info_high = ""
info_low = ""
info_high = line 
info_low = line
```

and it will be able to save the row information I need, and then I would just index the information that I need.

Comment: Why wouldn't this be an answer, it's saving the row information and finding the max/min.

Comment: Ah, I see what you are doing here. It's probably best to remove the "those suggestions are great" and format your answer to something that is easier to read. When others stumble upon a similar issue, this answer may not stand out as the solution to your problem (unless you accept it as the answer specifically)

Comment: thanks I'll edit this, and Carlos' answer above was probably a little bit more helpful than mine, a little bit more specific.